# WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams input html tag determine value of capture param

Tags: android, webview

I write custom browser of Android WebView. I override `onShowFileChooser` method of `WebChromeClient` and get `FileChooserParams` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams) from there. `FileChooserParams` has method `isCaptureEnabled()` which means that `<input>` HTML tag has `capture` parameter equals `user` or `enviroment` (front or back camera should be shown). In my code I want to determine this values to show front or back my custom camera depends on this param. Is there some method to get value of `capture` field?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture description of `capture` attribute